# Error DialogFragment starting in multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I currently got a ViewPager that has 3 tabs. Each tab is a fragment. I made a custom dialogFragment to login. I want that logindialog to open only when i go on my 3rd tab. In my onCreateView, i created a new object of my logindialog and show. My problem is, whenever i switch from my 1st tab to 2nd, the dialog also appears and i don't want that.

This is my viewpager adapter

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return frag1;
            case 1:
                return frag2;
            case 2:
                return frag3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

My 3rd Frag

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_annonce, container, false);

        DialogFragment loginDialog = new DialogFragment();
        loginDialog .show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "customLogin");

        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewPager` will create and retain "offscreen" pages as a performance optimization (with one offscreen page in either direction by default). What this means in practice is that when you are on Page 1, Page 2 has already been created off-screen. When you switch from Page 1 to Page 2, now Page 3 is created off-screen (and Page 1 is retained in case you want to switch back to it).

That means that `onCreateView()` is simply not the right place to show the error message.

You could perhaps create your own subclass of `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener` and override `onPageSelected()` to show the dialog.

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 2) {
            // show dialog
        }
    }
};

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);
```